# Написать валидацию в js для проверки существования объектов в контейнере

Tags: javascript, django, валидация

Вопрос в следующем.
Есть 2 модели в питоне - Recipe и Ingredient. У них есть связная модель RecipeIngredient.
Есть форма добавления рецепта и добавления ингредиентов из бд. Все прекрасно работает и сохраняет. НО...
Форма сохраняется не зависимо от того есть добавленные элементы ингредиентов или нет. Тк поле явно не указано в forms.py - то и поставить валидацию на его заполнение нет возможности(если же форму объявить, то required просто не даст сохранить форму, тк элементы добавляются в список, а само поле остается пустым).
Я новичок в python(а с js только начинаю знакомиться), потому, если я правильно понимаю задачу, нужно написать проверку контейнера в файле **formRecipe.js**, в который добавляются ингредиенты на существование объектов или вывести ошибку о необходимости заполнить поле. Помогите решить проблему, к сожалению, не нашел ответа на этот вопрос.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*models.py*

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=254, verbose_name='Название рецепта'
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Автор',
        related_name='recipes'
    )
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='recipes/images/',
        verbose_name='Фото рецепта',
    )
    text = models.TextField(
        verbose_name='Описание'
    )
    time_cooking = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name='Время приготовления'
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(
        verbose_name='Ссылка на рецепт',
        unique=True, null=True, blank=True
    )
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(
        Tag, through='TagRecipe',
        related_name='recipes',
        verbose_name='Тэг'
    )
    ingredient = models.ManyToManyField(
        Ingredient,
        through='RecipeIngredient',
        through_fields=('recipe', 'ingredient'),
        verbose_name='Ингридиент',
    )
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name='Дата публикации',
        auto_now_add=True,
    )

    objects = RecipeQuerySet.as_manager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-pub_date', )
        verbose_name = 'Рецепт'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Рецепты'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=254,
        verbose_name='Название ингредиента',
    )
    unit = models.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        verbose_name='Единица измерения'
    )

class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(
        Recipe,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Рецепт',
        related_name='recipe_ingredients',
    )
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(
        Ingredient,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Ингредиент',
        related_name='ingredient_recipes',
    )
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name='Количество',
    )
```

*view.py*

```
def get_ingredients(request):
    ingredients = {}
    for key in request.POST:
        if key.startswith('nameIngredient'):
            value_ingredient = key[15:]
            ingredients[request.POST[key]] = request.POST[
                'valueIngredient_' + value_ingredient
            ]
    return ingredients

@login_required
def recipe_create(request):
    form = RecipeForm(
        request.POST or None,
        files=request.FILES or None
    )
    ingredients = get_ingredients(request)
    if not form.is_valid():
        context = {
            'form': form,
            'is_new': True,
        }
        return render(
            request,
            'recipes/recipe_create.html',
            context
        )
    recipe = form.save(commit=False)
    recipe.author = request.user
    recipe.save()
    RecipeIngredient.objects.filter(recipe=recipe).delete()
    objs = []
    if ingredients is None:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            'А кто поле будет заполнять, Пушкин?',
            params={'ingredients': ingredients},
        )
    for title, count in ingredients.items():
        ingredient = get_object_or_404(Ingredient, title=title)
        objs.append(RecipeIngredient(
            recipe=recipe,
            ingredient=ingredient,
            count=count
        ))
    RecipeIngredient.objects.bulk_create(objs)
    form.save_m2m()
    return redirect('index')
```

*serializer.py + views.py*

```
class IngredientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = ('title', 'unit',)
        extra_kwargs = {'title': {'required': True}}

class GetIngredient(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.ListModelMixin):
    queryset = Ingredient.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = IngredientSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('title',)
```

*html*

```
{% extends "recipes/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
    {% if recipe_edit %}
        Добавить рецепт
    {% else %}
        Редактировать рецепт
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block static_css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'pages/form.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block heading %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% if recipe_edit %}
            <h1 class="main__title">Редактировать рецепт</h1>
        {% else %}
            <h1 class="main__title">Добавить рецепт</h1>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% load recipe_filters %}

<div class="form-container">
    <form class="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form__group">
            <label for="id_name" class="form__label">{{ form.title.label }}</label>
            <div class="form__field-group">
                {{ form.title|addclass:'form__input' }}
                <span class="form__error"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group">
            <p class="form__label">{{ form.tags.label }}</p>
            <div class="form__field-group">
                <div class="tags">
                    {% for tag in form.fields.tags.choices.queryset %}
                        <div class="tags__item">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="{{ tag.id }}" id="id_{{ tag.display_name }}"
                                class="tags__checkbox tags__checkbox_{{ tag.color }}" checked>
                            <label for="id_tags_{{ tag.id }}" class="tags__label">{{ tag.title }}</label>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <span class="form__error"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group">
            <label for="nameIngredient" class="form__label">Ингредиенты</label>
            <div class="form__field-group">
                <div class="form__field-group-ingredientes">
                    <div class="form__dropdown">
                        <input class="form__input" id="nameIngredient" type="text">
                        <div class="form__dropdown-items"></div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="number" id="cantidad" class="form__input" min="0">
                    <label for="cantidad" class="form__label" id="cantidadVal">шт</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form__field-group-ingredientes-container" ></div>
                <span class="form__ingredient-link" id="addIng">Добавить ингредиент</span>
                <span class="form__error"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group">
            <label for="id_time" class="form__label">{{ form.time_cooking.label }}</label>
            <div class="form__field-group form__field-group_time">
                {{ form.time_cooking|addclass:'form__input' }}
                <label for="id_time" class="form__label">минут</label>
                <span class="form__error"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group">
            <label for="id_description" class="form__label">{{ form.text.label }}</label>
            <div class="form__field-group">
                {{ form.text|addclass:'form__textarea' }}
                <span class="form__error"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group">
            <span class="form__label">{{ form.image.label }}</span>
            <div class="form__field-group">
                {{ form.image }}
                <span class="form__error"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form__footer">
            {% if recipe_edit %}
                <button type="submit" class="button button_style_blue">Редактировать рецепт</button>
            {% else %}
                <button type="submit" class="button button_style_blue">Создать рецепт</button>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block static_js %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/config/config.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/components/Header.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/utils/debouncing.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/api/Api.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'formRecipe.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

*formRecipe.js*

```
const counterId = document.querySelector('#counter');

const ingredientsContainer = document.querySelector('.form__field-group-ingredientes-container');
const nameIngredient = document.querySelector('#nameIngredient');
const formDropdownItems = document.querySelector('.form__dropdown-items');
const cantidadVal = document.querySelector('#cantidadVal');
const cantidad = document.querySelector('#cantidad')
const addIng = document.querySelector('#addIng');

const api = new Api(apiUrl);
const header = new Header(counterId);

const defineInitialIndex = function () {
    const ingredients = ingredientsContainer.querySelectorAll('.form__field-item-ingredient')
    if (ingredients.length === 0) { return 1 }
    const data = Array.from(ingredients).map(item => {
        if (!item.getAttribute('id')) { return 0 }
        if (!item.getAttribute('id').split('_')[1]) { return 0 }
        return Number(item.getAttribute('id').split('_')[1])
    })
    data.sort((a, b) => a-b)
    return data[data.length - 1] + 1
}

function Ingredients() {
    let cur = defineInitialIndex();
    // клик по элементам с сервера
    const dropdown = (e) => {
        if (e.target.classList.contains('form__item-list')) {
            nameIngredient.value = e.target.textContent;
            formDropdownItems.style.display = ''
            cantidadVal.textContent = e.target.getAttribute('data-val');
        }
    };
    // Добавление элемента из инпута
    const addIngredient = (e) => {
        if(nameIngredient.value && cantidad.value) {
            const data = getValue();
            const elem = document.createElement('div');
            elem.classList.add('form__field-item-ingredient');
            elem.id = `ing_${cur}`;
            elem.innerHTML = `<span> ${data.name} ${data.value}${data.units}</span> <span class="form__field-item-delete"></span>
                             <input id="nameIngredient_${cur}" name="nameIngredient_${cur}" type="hidden" value="${data.name}">
                             <input id="valueIngredient_${cur}" name="valueIngredient_${cur}" type="hidden" value="${data.value}">
                             <input id="unitsIngredient_${cur}" name="unitsIngredient_${cur}" type="hidden" value="${data.units}">`;
            cur++;
            
            ingredientsContainer.appendChild(elem);
        }
    };

    // удаление элемента

    const eventDelete = (e) => {
        if(e.target.classList.contains('form__field-item-delete')) {
            const item = e.target.closest('.form__field-item-ingredient');
            item.removeEventListener('click',eventDelete);
            item.remove()
        };
    };
    ingredientsContainer.addEventListener('click', eventDelete);
    // получение данных из инпутов для добавления
    const getValue = (e) => {
        const data = {
            name: nameIngredient.value,
            value: cantidad.value,
            units: cantidadVal.textContent
        };
        clearValue(nameIngredient);
        clearValue(cantidad);
        return data;
    };
    // очистка инпута
    const clearValue = (input) => {
        input.value = '';
    };
    return {
        clearValue,
        getValue,
        addIngredient,
        dropdown
    }
}

const cbEventInput = (elem) => {
    return api.getIngredients(elem.target.value).then( e => {
        if(e.length !== 0 ) {
            const items = e.map( elem => {
                return `<a class="form__item-list" data-val="${elem.unit}"">${elem.title}</a>`
            }).join(' ')
            formDropdownItems.style.display = 'flex';
            formDropdownItems.innerHTML = items;
        }
    })
    .catch( e => {
        console.log(e)
    })
};

const eventInput = debouncing(cbEventInput, 1000);

// вешаем апи
nameIngredient.addEventListener('input', eventInput);
const ingredients = Ingredients();
// вешаем слушатель на элементы с апи
formDropdownItems.addEventListener('click', ingredients.dropdown);
// вешаем слушатель на кнопку
addIng.addEventListener('click', ingredients.addIngredient);
```

Comment: Вообще с полем в форме должно все работать. Если не работает - то что то не так с кастомизацией. Попробуйте поменять на стандартне M2M поле и проверьте.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю проблема с этим. Укажите в форме необходимость заполнить 'ingridient` поле и смотрите п. 1 и 2 в коде ниже

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    ...
    ingredient = models.ManyToManyField( # <!- 1. Валидируйте это поле
        Ingredient,
        through='RecipeIngredient',
        through_fields=('recipe', 'ingredient'), # <!- Обычно это не нужно
        verbose_name='Ингридиент',
        # Я бы добавил тут related_name='recipes', чтобы получить доступ из Ингридентов сразу к Рецептам
    )
    ...

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    ...

class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(
        Recipe,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Рецепт',
        related_name='recipe_ingredients', # <- 2. Оно вам не нужно, См. 1 
    )
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(
        Ingredient,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Ингредиент',
        related_name='ingredient_recipes',
    )
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name='Количество',
    )
```